# File upload to a Node JS server

Tags: node.js

I am trying to upload a file to my node js server using express.
Here is my nodejs code:

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var fs=require('fs');
var sys=require('sys');
app.listen(8080);
app.get('/',function(req,res){
fs.readFile('upload.html',function (err, data){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html','Content-Length':data.length});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
});



});
app.post('/upload',function(req,res)
{
console.log(req.files);
fs.readFile(req.files.displayImage.path, function (err, data) {
  // ...
  var newPath = __dirname;
  fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
    res.redirect("back");
  });
});

});
```

My upload.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="uploadForm"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      action="/upload"
      method="post">
  <input type="file" id="userPhotoInput" name="displayImage" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<span id="status" />
<img id="uploadedImage" />


</body>
</html>
```

I am getting an error that the req.files is undefined.
What could be wrong? The file upload is also not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As noted in [the docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.files), `req.files`, along with `req.body` are provided by the `bodyParser` middleware.  You can add the middleware like this:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());

// or, as `req.files` is only provided by the multipart middleware, you could 
// add just that if you're not concerned with parsing non-multipart uploads, 
// like:
app.use(express.multipart());
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I shouldn't have missed that.